# Mahalanobis distance in matlab: pdist2() vs. mahal() function

Tags: matlab

I have two matrices X and Y. Both represent a number of positions in 3D-space. X is a 50*3 matrix, Y is a 60*3 matrix.

My question: why does applying the mean-function over the output of pdist2() in combination with 'Mahalanobis' not give the result obtained with mahal()?

More details on what I'm trying to do below, as well as the code I used to test this.

Let's suppose the 60 observations in matrix Y are obtained after an experimental manipulation of some kind. I'm trying to assess whether this manipulation had a significant effect on the positions observed in Y. Therefore, I used `pdist2(X,X,'Mahalanobis')` to compare X to X to obtain a baseline, and later, X to Y (with X the reference matrix: `pdist2(X,Y,'Mahalanobis')`), and I plotted both distributions to have a look at the overlap.

Subsequently, I calculated the mean Mahalanobis distance for both distributions and the 95% CI and did a t-test and Kolmogorov-Smirnoff test to asses if the difference between the distributions was significant. This seemed very intuitive to me, however, when testing with mahal(), I get different values, although the reference matrix is the same. I don't get what the difference between both ways of calculating mahalanobis distance is exactly.

Comment that is too long @3lectrologos: 
You mean this: d(I) = (Y(I,:)-mu)*inv(SIGMA)*(Y(I,:)-mu)'? This is just the formula for calculating mahalanobis, so should be the same for pdist2() and mahal() functions. I think mu is a scalar and SIGMA is a matrix based on the reference distribution as a whole in both pdist2() and mahal(). Only in mahal you are comparing each point of your sample set to the points of the reference distribution, while in pdist2 you are making pairwise comparisons based on a reference distribution. Actually, with my purpose in my mind, I think I should go for mahal() instead of pdist2(). I can interpret a pairwise distance based on a reference distribution, but I don't think it's what I need here.

```
% test pdist2 vs. mahal in matlab

% the purpose of this script is to see whether the average over the rows of E equals the values in d...

% data
X = []; % 50*3 matrix, data omitted
Y = []; % 60*3 matrix, data omitted


% calculations
S = nancov(X);

% mahal()
d = mahal(Y,X); % gives an 60*1 matrix with a value for each Cartesian element in Y (second matrix is always the reference matrix)

% pairwise mahalanobis distance with pdist2()
E = pdist2(X,Y,'mahalanobis',S); % outputs an 50*60 matrix with each ij-th element the pairwise distance between element X(i,:) and Y(j,:) based on the covariance matrix of X: nancov(X)
%{
 so this is harder to interpret than mahal(), as elements of Y are not just compared to the "mahalanobis-centroid" based on X,
% but to each individual element of X
% so the purpose of this script is to see whether the average over the rows of E equals the values in d...
%}

F = mean(E); % now I averaged over the rows, which means, over all values of X, the reference matrix

mean(d)
mean(E(:)) % not equal to mean(d)
d-F' % not zero

% plot output
figure(1)
plot(d,'bo'), hold on
plot(mean(E),'ro')
legend('mahal()','avaraged over all x values pdist2()')
ylabel('Mahalanobis distance')

figure(2)
plot(d,'bo'), hold on
plot(E','ro')
plot(d,'bo','MarkerFaceColor','b')
xlabel('values in matrix Y (Yi) ... or ... pairwise comparison Yi. (Yi vs. all Xi values)')
ylabel('Mahalanobis distance')
legend('mahal()','pdist2()')
```

Comment: Added code formatting and removed the final rant for you.

Answer (score 1):

One immediate difference between the two is that [`mahal`](http://www.mathworks.ch/ch/help/stats/mahal.html) subtracts the sample mean of `X` from each point in `Y` before computing distances.

Try something like `E = pdist2(X,Y-mean(X),'mahalanobis',S);` to see if that gives you the same results as `mahal`.

Comment: Where did you read this?
I tried E = pdist2(X,Y-repmat(mean(X),size(Y,1),1),'mahalanobis',S);
but this only increased the pairwise distances with +- the size of the mean subtracted... . I thus get huge distance values now, which are not correct... .

Comment: I read it in the Matlab documentation of the respective functions.

Comment: I added a response to your comment in the question. It was too long to post here.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

`mahal(X,Y)`

is equivalent to

`pdist2(X,mean(Y),'mahalanobis',cov(Y)).^2`

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess there are two different ways to calculate mahalanobis distance between two clusters of data like you explain above:
1) you compare each data point from your sample set to mu and sigma matrices calculated from your reference distribution (although labeling one cluster sample set and the other reference distribution may be arbitrary), thereby calculating the distance from each point to this so called mahalanobis-centroid of the reference distribution.
2) you compare each datapoint from matrix Y to each datapoint of matrix X, with, X the reference distribution (mu and sigma are calculated from X only)

The values of the distances will be different, but I guess the ordinal order of dissimilarity between clusters is preserved when using either method 1 or 2? I actually wonder when comparing 10 different clusters to a reference matrix X, or to each other, if the order of the dissimilarities would differ using method 1 or method 2? Also, I can't imagine a situation where one method would be wrong and the other method not. Although method 1 seems more intuitive in some situations, like mine.

Comment: I tested for many clusters and the ordinal property seems preserved over both methods, as well as part of the magnitude of the difference between clusters.